# OOP - How to define what object create?

Tags: php, oop

I ask your advise.
In my php file there are some classes.

```
class Template {

public $id;
public $title;
public $text;
public $description;
public $data = array();
public $content_html;
public $width_content = 500;
public $type;
public $time;
public $user;
public $category;
protected $CI;


// The next code works for a one element of array $data
function __construct($data = array()){
    $this->title    = $data['title'];
    $this->text     = $data['text'];
    $this->category = $data['category'];
    $this->type     = $data['type'];
    $this->time     = $data['time'];

    $this->CI =& get_instance();
    $this->user = new InformationUser($data);
}

class Articles extends Template {
}

class News extends Template {
}

class Init {
   public $posts = array('type' => 2);
}
```

The start point of my classes is a class Init.
Inside this class there is array of users posts.
In each element array there is a type value, which define what object class I must create.
For example:

```
class Init {
  function define(){
     foreach($this->posts as $val){
      if($val['type'] == 2){
        $article = new Articles($val);
        //TODO $articles
      } else if($val['type'] == 3){
        $news = new News($val);
         //TODO $news
        }
     }
  }
}
```

I know that is variant is wrong, better to put all array **posts()** to class. But I can not do this.
I need, that for different type of element of array - to work separate class (for news - News class, article - class Article etc.)
What do you advise me?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: i don't think is Init responsibility to do that, what i suggest you is to let Template be an interface (i.e. TemplateInterface) and let the "post type" aware side (a client of the service) to initialize the right Class that implements TemplateInterface

Comment: I try to get template for each data of array with a different type of data. Sorry for my bad explain

Comment: Maybe you are right about using Interface. Can you post a answer with a example Interfaces for my question, please?

Comment: Just some terms you should read about: [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance),
[solid principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29),
[single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle),
[ports and adapters architecture](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Hexagonal+architecture).

Comment: I still don't get what you want to achieve. Your Init is something like a Template Factory, which can be perfectly valid in this scenario. It should not contain the `TODO` code, just return the results, which should have the same interface. But it is uncertain whether they can have the same interface, there is not enough code to decide that. I'd rather use a single template instance instead of multiple ones, it will be faster with long arrays (but if it is not slow it does not matter).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the minimal info provided.. I assume you are looking for something like this:

```
    <?php
    class Init {
        public static function define($type, $text)
        {
          switch($type) {
            case 1:
                return new Articles($text);
            break;
            case 2:
                return new News($text);
            break;
            default:
                throw new Exception('Undefined type');
          }
        }
    }

// $template = Init::define(1, 'article text');
// $template = Init::define(2, 'news text');
```

Comment: I can write a full classes at question for more details, if it is a good idea and will not get a ban. May I?

Comment: You had showed answer not right. It is a same that i wrote, but with a static method. Still all calls a static method must be called for each element of the array in a loop